# UITableView that switch cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to have a tableview that has 2 cells.

One with a label that increases the height and one without that label. The user adds things to this tableview (sort of like a todo list) and if the user selects an option, the label is visible in the tableviewcell of the new item that they added, but if they don't select the option, then they add a tableviewcell without that label. Is there anyway in which I can choose when to display the cell with the label.

I first thought of just making the label invisible if the option isn't selected, however that affect the height of the other label and the constraints.

Would it be possible to create 2 different cells with different identifiers, and call which one to add depending on whether the option is selected.

According to solutions, I tried switching between 2 different cells and this was my code for doing so.

```
if newMode==true{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "monthlyCell", for: indexPath) as! MonthlyExpenseTableViewCell
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        cell.dateLabelBackground.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: 31)
        cell.dateLabel.text = dateString
        cell.expenseName2.text = expense.name
        cell.expenseAmount2.text = finalDisplayed
        cell.expenseCategory2.text = expense.category
        cell.expenseCollection2.text = expense.collection
        if (expense.expense) {
            cell.expenseAmount2.textColor = UIColor.red
        }


        else if (expense.income){
            cell.expenseAmount2.textColor = UIColor.green
        }

        if (expense.cash) && (expense.expense){
            cell.cashOrCredit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Cash-Expense Icon")

        }
        else if (expense.cash) && (expense.income){
            cell.cashOrCredit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Cash-Income Icon")

        }
        else if (expense.credit) && (expense.income){
            cell.cashOrCredit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Credit-Income Icon")

        }
        else if (expense.credit) && (expense.income){
            cell.cashOrCredit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Credit-Expense Icon")

        }
    }
    else if newMode==false{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "monthlyCell2", for: indexPath) as! MonthlyExpenseTableViewCellShort
        cell.expenseName3.text = expense.name
        cell.expenseAmount3.text = finalDisplayed
        cell.expenseCategory3.text = expense.category
        cell.expenseCollection3.text = expense.collection
        if (expense.expense) {
            cell.expenseAmount3.textColor = UIColor.red
        }


        else if (expense.income){
            cell.expenseAmount3.textColor = UIColor(red:0.49, green:0.83, blue:0.13, alpha:1.0)
        }

        if (expense.cash) && (expense.expense){
            cell.cashOrCredit3.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Cash-Expense Icon")

        }
        else if (expense.cash) && (expense.income){
            cell.cashOrCredit3.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Cash-Income Icon")

        }
        else if (expense.credit) && (expense.income){
            cell.cashOrCredit3.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Credit-Income Icon")

        }
        else if (expense.credit) && (expense.income){
            cell.cashOrCredit3.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Credit-Expense Icon")

        }
    }
    return cell
```

}

The problem with this, is that it only returns on cell at a time for some reason. When I delete the cell, it shows the next one.

Here is the code for me setting the boolean "newMode"

```
if indexPath.row == 0{
        newMode = true
    }
    if indexPath.row>1{
    let previousExpensesData = monthlyExpenses[indexPath.row - 1].modificationDate
        let day = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: expense.modificationDate as! Date) // Do not add above 'date' value here, you might get some garbage value. I know the code is redundant. You can adjust that.
        let previousDay = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: monthlyExpenses[indexPath.row - 1].modificationDate! as Date)
        if day == previousDay {
            newMode = false
        } else {
            newMode = true
        }
    }
```

For my heightForRowAtIndexPath, I use this code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    if newMode==true {
            return 95
        }
        else if newMode==false {

            return 64
        }
        else {
            return 0
        }
}
```

And this is the code for numberOfRows

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if monthlyExpenses.count == 0{
        noExpenseLabel.isHidden = false
    }
    return monthlyExpenses.count
}
```

Here are what the 2 cells look like

[image]

Comment: yes you can just create two custom cells. In your cellForRowAt function check to see which should be used and return that one.

Comment: I tried adding two different cells, but now when I return them using an if condition, only one item at a time gets returned instead of the whole array of items

Comment: Show your code, we can't diagnose issues without being able to see the problem

Comment: @Scriptable I have added all the necessary code, pleas have a look and help!

Comment: What code do you have in `numberOfRows(in: section)` and `heightForRowAt`?

Comment: @Scriptable Updated, still don't understand why only one expense shows at a time?

Comment: if only one cell is showing you need to check the data source, the numberOfSections, numberOfRows etc. it is strange but not enough info here for me to say for sure

Comment: @Scriptable My numberOfSections, returns 1. My numberOfRows code is added above now

Comment: code seems ok, I would put some breakpoints in and make sure the correct value is being returned from numberOfRows in, put a breakdpoint in cellForRowAt too and see how often it is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you will no need of having two different cell. As you just said in your question  "I first thought of just making the label invisible if the option isn't selected, however that affect the height of the other label and the constraints."

Just use one cell.

Now to overcome this thing use UIStackView.Put that label in this stackView. Give proper constraints to stackView. And hide/unhide the label according to your option. UIStackView will do the things for you. :)

It will give you the result as you want. For more information about UIStackView, read [this awesome tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/160646/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views-2) by Raywenderlich.

**EDIT: As per your comment**

I have created a cell like this..

[image]

I managed all subviews of that cell like this..

[image]

And I just wrote a line of code in `cellForRow`

```
cell.label.isHidden =  indexPath.row % 2 == 1
```

And I'm getting the output this....

[image]

Comment: When I use a stackView, all my constraints get messed up and I am unable to align them properly.

Comment: Can you add your cell xib screenshot and please mention which label you have to hide/unhide?

Comment: Sure done it, as you can see, I have different layers in my cell which I can't align in a stack view. Currently you can see 2 cells, but if I could get it done in one, that would be great. The date expense label at the top, is what I have to hide. Other than that, the 2 labels are identical.

Comment: I have modified my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Is the rest of my code fine, for e.g. do you return anything in heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Also, I'm sorry but nothing happened by implementing that line of code. All it did was make the date label visible  for all expenses regardless of the date before. What exactly does the line of code mean, maybe I can alter it a little bit?

Comment: I don't use heightForRowAtIndexPath. I let 'tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension' do the height thing for me. And That line of code is just an example of hiding/unhiding label , Rest code will be according to your requirement in cellForRow. I have just shown that what will happen with the cell when I hide or unhide that label. Believe me, there is no other code i have written to achieve this.

Comment: So where you unhide the label, it automatically adjusts the height and all the constraints?

Comment: yeah. cause of stackView which I have used for label , that makes it possible without doing anything.

Comment: And all of your constraints are top constraints form the components, or bottom constraints from the stackview? Because I have done exactly as you have, but nothing happens :( Also, did you use any estimated row height

Comment: In second image in my answer, I have mentioned all the constraints I have used. you need to look closely. And in Xcode 9+ , you don't need to specify rowHeight or estimatedRowheight for a tableView. Storyboard does this work for you.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please send me your Xcode project, my email address is: arnav2114@gmail.com